# ¿Es posible hacer una especie de WHERE *?

Tags: mysql

Busco hacer una consulta que haga una selección completa de la `tabla` que selecciono donde alguno de todos los campos existentes en la `db` coincida al valor de búsqueda, esto implica que se muestren los datos que existan en la base de datos con un valor igual al ingresado, me explico:

Tengo un campo de búsqueda en el cual al ingresar una palabra quiero que se busque en la db.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias_blog WHERE unodetodoslosdatos='$busqueda'";
```

Por el momento lo tengo de esta forma el código:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias_blog WHERE fecha='$busqueda' OR titulo='$busqueda' OR dcorta='$busqueda' OR dlarga='$busqueda'"
```

[image: Buscar]

De esta manera la persona ingresara un valor de búsqueda y este debiera compararse con todas las tablas a ver si existe.

Comment: Te refieres a una busqueda por todos los campos de una tabla?

Comment: todas las tablas?? o seran todos los campos de una tabla?? o todos los campos de todas las tablas??? o los nombres de las tablas??? igual, es bastante poco practico..

Comment: mira este enlace, creo que te puede servir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435963/how-to-find-a-string-inside-a-entire-database

Comment: Todos los campos de una tabla, no todas las tablas.

Comment: @DanielGS el problema de esa pregunta es que, compara un valor con los nombres de las bases de datos y de las columnas, yo busco comparar los datos en los campos de una tabla

Comment: **[Esto es lo que buscas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18416337/5587982)**: `SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE MATCH(`campo1`, `foo`, `bar`) AGAINST ('$search')` Pero **lee bien** la documentación [Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: ¿Necesitas encontrar las filas de una tabla donde cualquier campo de dicha tabla pueda ser igual al valor de la busqueda ingresadA?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas hacer es un

```
SELECT <CAMPOS> 
FROM <TABLA>
WHERE MATCH (<CAMPO_1>, <CAMPO_2>) 
AGAINST (<VALOR DE LA BÚSQUEDA INGRESADA>)
```

Entonces, en tu caso, sería algo así:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_noticias_blog 
        WHERE MATCH (`nombre_de_tus_campos`) 
        AGAINST ('" . $busqueda . "')";
```

Puedes usar [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) para utilizar operadores dentro de la búsqueda y especificar si quieres que sea una búsqueda de tipo `AND` o `NOT` de la siguiente forma, (si no se específica ningún operador se utilizará por defecto el `OR`):

```
+ = AND

- = NOT

[ningún operador] = OR
```

Entonces puedes intentar también con una consulta así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_noticias_blog 
WHERE MATCH (`titulo`, `descripcion`) 
AGAINST ('+Titulo' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

La que se puede traducir como que estás buscando filas donde el valor de `'Titulo'` se encuentre tanto en el campo `titulo` como en el campo `descripcion`

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias_blog WHERE MATCH (fecha, titulo, dcorta, dlarga) AGAINST (DDDD);
Utilice esa consulta pero SQL da error: 
/* Error de SQL (1054): Unknown column 'DDDD' in 'where clause' */
y DDDD existe como dato

Comment: Probe con where match de las maneras que planteaste, debe estar de forma correcta pero no es la solución para mi problema. E intentado hacerlo con WHERE ... OR ...OR like ... pero me envia todos los datos de la tabla

Comment: En el ejemplo `DDDD` no es una columna, sino el valor a buscar, que debe ir entre comillas simples, @felipeandrade o ser pasado en forma de variable. Lee mi comentario en la pregunta, arriba.

Comment: @A.Cedano SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE MATCH(titulo, dcorta, dlarga) AGAINST 'cvcv' esta consulta como la muestras manda un error:  /* Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''cvcv'' at line 1 */

Comment: @felipeandrade el valor después de `AGAINST` debe ir entre paréntesis. Si le hubieras hecho caso a mi comentario ya tendrías el problema resuelto. Te preparé un fiddle de ejemplo.

Comment: mira esta consulta, el valor que busco existen como dato en la tabla:
SELECT *
FROM tbl_noticias_blog 
WHERE MATCH (fecha, titulo, dcorta, dlarga) 
AGAINST (HECTOR);

me da este resultado : /* Error de SQL (1054): Unknown column 'HECTOR' in 'where clause' */

Comment: @felipeandrade el valor HECTOR, debe ir entre comillas

Comment: si lo pongo entre comillas da este error: /* Error de SQL (1271): Illegal mix of collations for operation 'match' */

Comment: Observa mi respuesta y el demo, @felipeandrade

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar un valor en diferentes columnas de una tabla necesitas crear un índice `FULLTEXT` que indique las columnas que intervendrán en la búsqueda, por ejemplo:

```
    FULLTEXT(contenido1, contenido2)
```

La consulta sería entonces así:

```
SELECT * FROM buscar_20170906 
    WHERE MATCH(contenido1, contenido2) 
    AGAINST ('lo que busco');
```

- En `MATCH()` las columnas que intervienen, las que tienen índice `FULLTEXT`
- En `AGAINST()`  el valor a buscar.

---

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/RBII91393)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS buscar_20170906 (
    publicacion_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    contenido1 TEXT,
    contenido2 TEXT,
    FULLTEXT(contenido1, contenido2)
);

INSERT INTO buscar_20170906 (contenido1, contenido2)
    VALUES 
        ('Lorem ipsum','lo que busco'),
        ('Otro Lorem ipsum de Santiago',''),
        ('dolor sit amet', 'lo que busco'),
        ('Otro dolor sit amet','')
;

SELECT * FROM buscar_20170906 
    WHERE MATCH(contenido1, contenido2) 
    AGAINST ('lo que busco');
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
publicacion_id       contenido1      contenido2
1                    Lorem ipsum     lo que busco
3                    dolor sit amet  lo que busco
```

---

**Notas:**

- Hay varios tipos de búsqueda `FULLTEXT`, es importante que leas al respecto  [la documentación sobre fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)
- Si las tablas están en InnoDB y tu versión de MySQL es inferior a 5.6, no es posible usar `FULLTEXT`. En ese sentido deberás actualizar MySQL o crear una tabla del tipo MyISAM.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias_blog 
WHERE MATCH(titulo, dcorta, dlarga) 
AGAINST ('hola');
/* Error de SQL (1191): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list */
/* Filas afectadas: 0  Filas encontradas: 0  Advertencias: 0  Duración para 0 of 1 consulta: 0,000 sec. */

Comment: Es lo que te decía @felipeandrade, si quieres hacer ese tipo de búsqueda **tu tabla debe tener un índice `FULLTEXT` que incluya todas las columnas sobre las que quieres aplicar la búsqueda**, en este caso: `FULLTEXT (titulo, dcorta, dlarga)` mira el `CREATE TABLE` de la respuesta para que veas cómo se crea dicho índice.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo con algun artificio, se me ocurre unir los campos para no comparar uno por uno:

```
select * from tbl_noticias_blog where (campo1+campo2+campo3+campon) like '%$busqueda%'

select * from tbl_noticias_blog where CONCAT(campo1,campo2,campo3,campon) like '%$busqueda%'

select * from tbl_noticias_blog where (campo1||campo2||campo3||campon) like '%$busqueda%'
```

Varia la forma de unir segun el motor de Base de Datos.